# VBA - Excel TextBox1 assign object to varaible

Tags: excel, vba

I get error when I try to assign TextBox1 to variable X.

```
Sub TB1()
   Dim X As TextBox
   Dim Y As String
   X = TextBox1
   If Len(X) < 4 Then
     Y = X
     Do
        Y = "0" & Y
     Loop Until Len(Y) >= 4
     X = Y
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the error you get? What line is it on? Please edit your question to include those details. Thank you.

Comment: Well. You never specify the object `TextBox1` belongs to it? Is it on a Worksheet? If so, which one? Is it on a UserForm? If so, which one? For example `X = Me.TextBox1` or `X = Sheets("Sheet1").TextBox1`

Comment: Error is on X = TextBox1    The textbox is on a worksheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a few issues.  See comments for details in the code

```
Sub TB1()
   Dim X As TextBox
   Dim Y As String

   Set X = Me.TextBoxes("Textbox 1")   
   'You need to have some sort of reference to get to the textbox.  
   'Me in this case is a worksheet object I tested in the Sheet1 module.  
   'It has a collection of textboxes which you can refer to by name.  Click on your textbox in excel to see the name in the upper left corner.
   'The `Set` syntax is necessary for objects 

   If Len(X.Text) < 4 Then
     Y = X.Text 
     'Have to explicitly refer to the text in the textbox since it has other properties you can change like height and width
     Do
        Y = "0" & Y
     Loop Until Len(Y) >= 4
     X.Text = Y 'Explicitly refer to the textbox text again to reassign
   End If
End Sub
```