# VBA Text Box not returning entered value

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code that copies a number of lines to a different point in the sheet. At present the number of lines is defined by the user by way of a cell value, however I am trying to change to using a text box to enter the value, not a cell.

I added a message box to check the value of the text box, but regardless what number I enter it always returns as 0.

```
Dim NumofRows As Integer

NumofRows = CInt(TextBox1)

MsgBox (NumofRows)

If NumofRows = 0 Then
    NumofRows = 1
End If

Range("A500").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
ActiveCell.Rows("1:" & NumofRows).EntireRow.Copy
Range("A2").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(1).EntireRow.Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

The textbox is called TextBox1. Can anyone suggest how to correct this? Many thanks.

Comment: I answered a similar question recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35461024/vba-excel-textbox1-assign-object-to-varaible/35461962#35461962

Comment: What kind of textbox is it and where is it (worksheet or userform)?

Comment: I saw that questions @Sobigen however even defining the sheet still with `ActiveSheet.TextBoxes("TextBox1")` returned 0. It is a stand alone text box in a worksheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have a text box on a sheet.
Please try this : example you have "Sheet1"

```
NumofRows = CInt(Sheets("Sheet1").TextBox1.Value)
```